# rest with jersey struts2 spring3 not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, struts2, jersey

I am trying to expose webservice using jersey for a struts2 spring3 web application

**my web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.vxl.appanalytix.service.impl</param-value>
        </init-param>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In **struts.xml** i have added excludePattern

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*" />
```

**service class**

```
@Path("/requirement")
@Service("dimRequirementManager")
public class DimRequirementManagerImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<DimRequirement, Long> implements DimRequirementManager {
    @Autowired
    DimRequirementDao dimRequirementDao;
    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public DimRequirement getDimRequirement(){
    DimRequirement dimRequirement = new DimRequirement();
    dimRequirement.setClientKey(123L);
    dimRequirement.setPriority("HIGH");

    return dimRequirement;
}}
```

**dependency**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I am passing the below url in the restclient `http://localhost:8080/app-web/rest/requirement/count` its returning

```
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 05:47:27 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

when debuging control is not going to the **getDimRequirement()**

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the `struts.xml` is the problem. I see that you have `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*" />` and you are trying a URL that does not fit in that pattern since it has not `.` Maybe you could try with `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/*" />` instead.

Comment: i get this error `There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [rest/requirement/count] associated with context path [/appanalytix-web]. - [unknown location]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem. i had a url rewrite filter in my web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
      <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
      <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

in the **urlrewrite.xml** i have added

```
<rule>
        <from>/rest/**</from>
        <to>/rest/$1</to>
    </rule>
```

Comment: Would you mind to add more code? (Full web.xml) I've the same issue. In my case, I have a developed app in struts2 and now we want to integrate rest services with spring MVC. I would like to exclude Struts2 from watching /rest... But in the HttpServletRequest of a rest controller I receive an struts2 instance. I implemented what you exaplained with no success by the moment. Thanks

Comment: have you added `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*" />` in your struts.xml. this is what most of them told me to do

Comment: Neither value="/rest/*" nor "/rest/*" work. I replaced struts * filter by *.html in web.xml to make it work but I would like to use the struts logic to exclude patterns because some day it could be possible that a new servlet serves html's