# jersey rest services showing exception javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jersey

I am working on jersey services which i mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997472/rest-with-jersey-struts2-spring3-not-working) it is working fine when i am returning a java object. Later i tried to make the java object generic its giving exception
**javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AppObject<T> implements Serializable {

    private List<T> list;
    private String license;

    public AppObject() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();

    }

    public AppObject(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getLicense() {
        return license;
    }

    public void setLicense(String license) {
        this.license = license;
    }

}
```

**my service**

```
@GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/getreq")
    public  AppObject<DimRequirement> savePayment() {
        AppObject<DimRequirement> appObject = new AppObject<DimRequirement>();
        appObject.setLicense("4");
        Long clientKey=4L;
        List<DimRequirement> dimreqlist = dimRequirementDao.getAllByClientNIsCurrent(clientKey);
        appObject.setList(dimreqlist);
        return appObject;

    }
```

**DimRequirement which is setting to AppObject**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DimRequirement extends BaseObject implements Serializable {
private Long requirementKey;
private String description;
private String priority;
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="requirementKey")
    public Long getRequirementKey() {
        return this.requirementKey;
    }    
    public void setRequirementKey(Long requirementKey) {
        this.requirementKey = requirementKey;
    }
 @Column(name="Description") 
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
 @Column(name="Priority") 
    public String getPriority() {
        return this.priority;
    }    
    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

**stack trace**

```
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class com.vxl.model.DimRequirement nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.vxl.model.DimRequirement nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
```

I referd following links 
[link 1](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html)
[link 2](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html)
but i was not able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your `get` method, the corresponding `JAXBContext` will be built on the class `AppObject` and not the type `AppObject<DimRequirement>`.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/getreq")
public  AppObject<DimRequirement> savePayment() {
```

You can make the `JAXBContext` that will be created on the `AppObject` class aware of `DimRequirement` by using the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({DimRequirement.class})
public class AppObject<T> implements Serializable {
```

Comment: thanks man it worked. I actually wanted to pass different objects for every HTTP GET .Can I add more than one `@XmlSeeAlso({xxxxx.class}) @XmlSeeAlso({yyyyy.class})`

Comment: @user2334391 - You could do `@XmlSeeAlso({xxxxx.class, yyyyy.class})`.

Comment: `{"license":"12345","dimRequirement":[{"alternateId":"AlternateID","classification":"1"}]` this is the json string its retrieving. but when i am parsing it gives error `**Unrecognized field "dimRequirement" (Class com.vxl.AppanalytixObject), not marked as ignorable**`