# unable to parse json string to a generic java object

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I am working on a jersey web services.
[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113280/jersey-rest-services-showing-exception-javax-ws-rs-webapplicationexception-java) following is the json string i received at my jersey client

```
{"license":"12345","dimRequirement":[{"alternateId":"AlternateID","classificati‌​on":"1"}] }
```

but when i am parsing it gives error.I used jackson for parsing

```
    Unrecognized field "dimRequirement" (Class com.vxl.AppObject), not marked as ignorable
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7be6f06c; line: 1, column: 49] (through reference chain: com.vxl.appanalytix.AppObject["dimRequirement"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:589)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:575)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:684)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:515)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2131)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1402)
    at com.vxl.CheckJersy.main(CheckJersy.java:56)
```

i tried by adding type Reference for parsing

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                output,new TypeReference<AppObject<DimRequirement>>() { } );
```

**generic class**

```
    @XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({ DimRequirement.class})
    public class AppObject<T> implements Serializable {

        private List<T> list;
        private String license;

        public AppObject() {
            list = new ArrayList<T>();

        }

        public AppObject(List<T> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        public List<T> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(List<T> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public String getLicense() {
            return license;
        }

        public void setLicense(String license) {
            this.license = license;
        }

    }
```

**services**
I want to use the same service for more than one POST request returning  `AppObject<xxx>,AppObject<yyy>`

```
@POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("/getreq")
    @Override
    public AppObject getAllByClientNIsCurrent(
            AppObject<DimRequirement> appObject) {
        List<DimRequirement> dimreqlist = dimRequirementDao
                .getAllByClientNIsCurrent(appObject.getClientKey());
        AppObject<DimRequirement> appObject = new AppObject<DimRequirement>();
        appObject.setList(dimreqlist);
        return appObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AppObject class has a field that is not present in the JSON.  You need to make the class with a jackson annotation to say it can be ignored.

Comment: check the edited code. AppObject is generic, from server side its returning a AppObject<DimRequirement> [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113280/jersey-rest-services-showing-exception-javax-ws-rs-webapplicationexception-java)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, about my other answer, please ignore it.

I got your code working exactly as is. All that was needed was the variable "list" needs to be named "dimRequirement" for the auto-mapping to work. You will also need to amend the getters and setters for this, as some Jackson settings can make the library use them.

Comment: please check the question i have added the service. I want to use the same service for more than one POST request returning `AppObject<xxx>,AppObject<yyy>`

Comment: Or is there any way to make the json string having a field **list** insted of **dimRequirement** for any generic object