# Restlet and Jersey co-exist together?

Tags: jersey, war, rcp, restlet

I have seen few examples such as [Using Spring and Jersey together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351422/using-spring-and-jersey-together). I am working on a scenario where I have a Jersey project which is packaged into a different WAR. I want to move that one into another WAR which is based on Restlet framework. The following updates I made:
1) Added the Jersey project to the POM as dependency.
2) Added the Configuration file JerseyApplication.java

```
public class JerseyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    final JAXRSResourceConfig instance = JAXRSResourceConfig.getInstance();
    return SetUtils.newSet(instance.getClasses());
}

}
```

Now there are two configuration file. One to load Jersey resources which is mentioned above and one which was present for the restlet.Folowing is the restlet config file:

```
public class Application extends org.restlet.Application {
@Override
public void handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
    super.handle(request, response);
}

public Application(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public Restlet createRoot() {
    final Context context = getContext();
    final Router root = new Router(context);
    // Add JaxRS resources
    final JaxRsRestlet jaxRS = new JaxRsRestlet(context, getMetadataService());
    jaxRS.addClass(XYZ.class);
    return root;
}
}
```

3) Updated web.xml :

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
    <param-value><Application.java PATH></param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Restlet adapter -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.attribute.application</param-name>
        <param-value><PACKAGE_PATH></param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- Jersey adapter -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value><CLASS PATH></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I want to know that is it possible that Restlet and Jersey projects both can co-exist together in a WAR packaging? I know that we can configure multiple servlets. Thanks in advance for any leads and suggestions on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why *Restlet* and *Jersey* would not be able to co-exist, I have a Restlet-based backend which has standard servlet code which works just fine. It will all boil down to the `web.xml` configuration.